# Excelアドイン（VSTO）でアドインもしくはExcelがフォーカスを失った（他のアプリが選択された）事を検知したい

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net, excel

お世話になります。

VB.NET(FrameWork4.0)でエクセル（2007）で動作するアドイン（ＶＳＴＯ）を作成しております。

表題の通りでございますがエクセルからタスクバー等を通じて他のアプリケーションが選択された時にアドイン側でフォーカスを失った（Deactive)になった事を知る方法はございますでしょうか？

VisualStudio2010でRibbon1.vbやThisAddIn.vbのイベントを調べてみましたが所要の要件を満たすイベントがありませんでした。

ご存知の方居られましたらご協力お願いします。

※回答を受けてThisAddIn.vbを以下のように修正

`Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`
 `Public Class ThisAddIn`
    `Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup`
        `AddHandler Me.Application.WindowDeactivate, AddressOf 　Me.Application_WindowDeactivate`
    `End Sub`

    `Private Sub ThisAddIn_Shutdown() Handles Me.Shutdown`

    `End Sub`
    `Private Sub Application_WindowDeactivate(Wb As　Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Workbook, Wn As Window)`
        `MsgBox("Deactive")`
    `End Sub`
`End Class`

と修正後、デバッグを実行してExcelが立ち上がった事を確認後、下のタスクバーから他のソフトをアクティブにしても Msgboxは動作しませんでした。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application`クラスのイベントを利用すればよいのではないかと思います。

まず、`ThisAddIn_Startup`等でイベントハンドラーを登録します。

```
AddHandler Me.Application.WindowDeactivate, AddressOf Application_WindowDeactivate
```

登録するイベントハンドラーのシグネチャは以下のようになります。

```
Private Sub Application_WindowDeactivate(Wb As Workbook, Wn As Window)

End Sub
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。ご指摘のコードを修正後の質問のようにThisAddIn.vbをコード修正したところ上手く動きませんでした。イベントハンドラーのシグネチャを記述する位置に問題があるのでしょうか？

Comment: 色々と試してみましたがWordの場合は上手く動作しましたが、ExcelではExcel2010とVS2015に変えてみても変化はありませんでした。

もう少し整理して再質問したいと思いますのでいったんこの質問はクローズします。

@pgrho様　回答ありがとうございました。