# ExcelのアドインがMicrosoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Applicationのイベントをハンドルしない

Tags: vb.net, excel, ms-word

表題の件に付きお助け頂けませんでしょうか？

前回[Excelアドイン（VSTO）でアドインもしくはExcelがフォーカスを失った（他のアプリが選択された）事を検知したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/22291/excel%E3%82%A2%E3%83%89%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3-vsto-%E3%81%A7%E3%82%A2%E3%83%89%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%82%E3%81%97%E3%81%8F%E3%81%AFexcel%E3%81%8C%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AB%E3%82%B9%E3%82%92%E5%A4%B1%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F-%E4%BB%96%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%81%8C%E9%81%B8%E6%8A%9E%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%9F-%E4%BA%8B%E3%82%92%E6%A4%9C%E7%9F%A5%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)で質問した者です。

その際Excelがフォーカスを失った事をMicrosoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationクラスのDeactiveWindowイベントで捕まえれば良いとアドバイスを受けテスト用にサンプルを組んでみましたがイベントをキャッチしてくれません。

```
Public Class ThisAddIn

Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup
    MsgBox("startup")
    AddHandler Me.Application.WindowDeactivate, AddressOf Application_WindowDeactivate
End Sub

Private Sub Application_WindowDeactivate(Wb As Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Workbook, wn As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Window)
    MsgBox("deactive")
End Sub

Private Sub ThisAddIn_Shutdown() Handles Me.Shutdown
End Sub
End Class
```

VS2010のデバッグでアドイン起動そしてエクセルが表示されますがここで別のアプリケーション（Google CHROME）をタスクバーから選択してExcelをDeactiveにしてもApplication_WindowDeactivateが実行されません。

ここでExcelではなくWord2007で以下のアドインを実行すると期待通りDeactiveイベントをキャッチして所要の動きをします。

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Public Class ThisAddIn

Dim initialized As Boolean = False

Private Sub InitializeCustom()
    initialized = True
    AddHandler Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.WindowDeactivate, AddressOf Application_WindowActivate
End Sub

Private Sub Application_WindowActivate(Doc As Word.Document, Wn As Word.Window)
    MessageBox.Show("Application_WindowActivate")
End Sub

Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup
    Me.InitializeCustom()
End Sub

Private Sub ThisAddIn_Shutdown() Handles Me.Shutdown

End Sub

End Class
```

ExcelとWordでどのような差があってExcelでイベントを掴めていないのかが色々考えているのですが想像できません。

どなたか直接の解決策でなくても良いので調べ方や検証の仕方などございましたらお助け頂けますでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ExcelとWordの差はMDIであるかどうかだと思います。Excelの親ウィンドウ側のイベントは`SetWinEventHook`などを使用すればハンドル出来なくはないのではないでしょうか。

Comment: @pgrho さま、WindowsAPIの利用ですね、回答がつくまでの間こちらでもGetForegroundWindowでハンドルをとにかく何かをクリックしたタイミングもしくは別スレッドで定期的に監視しようと考えておりましたがhookした方がスマートそうですね。ありがとうございます。ExcelとWordの差はMDI、ありがとうございます。Me.Application.WindowDeactivateだと子ウインドウをつかんでしまうと言うことでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class ThisAddIn

    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup
        Dim myExcelWindow = New ExcelWindow()
        myExcelWindow.AssignHandle(New IntPtr(Application.Hwnd))
        AddHandler myExcelWindow.Deactivate, AddressOf MyExcelWindow_Deactivate
    End Sub

    Private Sub MyExcelWindow_Deactivate(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("MyExcelWindow_Deactivate")
    End Sub

    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Shutdown() Handles Me.Shutdown
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class ExcelWindow
    Inherits NativeWindow
    Public Event Deactivate As EventHandler
    Const WM_ACTIVATED As Integer = &H6
    Const WM_SYSCOMMAND As Integer = &H112
    Const WA_INACTIVE As Integer = &H0
    Const SC_CLOSE As Integer = &HF060

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
        If m.Msg = WM_ACTIVATED AndAlso m.WParam.ToInt32() = WA_INACTIVE Then
            RaiseEvent Deactivate(Me, New EventArgs())
        ElseIf m.Msg = WM_SYSCOMMAND AndAlso m.WParam.ToInt32() = SC_CLOSE Then
            Me.ReleaseHandle()
        End If

        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End Sub
End Class
```

C#で書いたものをコンバーターで変換したので、正しいVB.NETの構文かどうかあまり自信ありません。一応動作は確認していますが。

Comment: @user13314さま　サンプルコードの提示ありがとうございます。当方でも動作確認が取れております。　NativeWindowクラスを継承したExcelWindowクラスをインスタンス化してそれのDeactivceイベントを取得しているように理解しました。　ここで疑問なのですがインスタンス化されたmyExcelWindowクラスはどこでエクセル自身のウインドウであると言う情報が紐づくのでしょうか？　NativeWindowクラス自体にコードが実行されているアプリケーションのウインドウを表すクラスと言う事でしょうか？

Comment: AssignHandleメソッドの引数としてExcelのウィンドウハンドル(Application.Hwnd)を渡しています。
詳しくはドキュメントを参照してみてください。
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.windows.forms.nativewindow(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @user13314さま ありがとうございます。納得できました。